# Extremely confusing for-loop behaviour

Tags: c#

I'm encountering an extremely strange behaviour with this code fragment.
Normally the for Statement doesnt enter when counted to 16 but leaves.
In my case it enters with `i=16` and executes the the Zero-Case which ends in an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

This behavior is repeated every time I call `foo()`
Is there any explanation for this?

```
void foo()
{
  Thread.Sleep(2000);
  try
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
      #region Switch
        (switch on 0 to 15 and do something unrelated)
      #endregion 
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Exception occured: " + ex);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have not given us the code that causes an error.

Comment: wihtout seeing the internals of the for loop, the issue must occur there.  something is changing the value of i inside the for loop.

Comment: post the part where the array is created, and the part where it is accessed. and the stacktrace.

Comment: Try changing the name of the switch-counter to 'switchCounter'.

Comment: `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` are you sure? No such exception in .Net!

Comment: IndexOutOfBounds. The Array Size is 16, so 0-15 is addressable, debugger confirms this. after the 15 is entered it iterates to 16 and enters the first case and breaks.

Comment: Please give us your Switch(){}! Because the problem is not in your above code.

Comment: Well, I can't post an answer now since the question is on hold. But the reason you are getting the error is that `BeginInvoke` queues the operation for the UI-thread to execute when it is idle. Therefore, when the code actually runs the value of the for-loop variable will have reached the final value which is 16. You have assumed that the code in the lambda sent to `BeginInvoke` will execute with the value of `i` at the time of adding it to the queue. It does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not loop upto your array length?

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    //Your secret code here
}
```

Also make sure you're not changing the value of `i` inside the loop anywhere.

You'll never get the exception with this code(unless you modify `i` inside the loop) irrespective of array Length.

Comment: +1 for `your secret code here`

Comment: I loop over the array length normally, but I want to find the error so I used different values

Comment: @JulianSchaefer If you have posted your original code, then you'd have got the answer within few mins. Since you're not interested to show your code this is what we can give as help. :)

Comment: I edited my first post. Instead of downvoting, why dont you check it out?

Comment: @JulianSchaefer I see you have posted an image, but can't see what it is because I'm behind a firewall, if it contians relevant code can you add it to the question (the actual code I mean)?

Comment: contents of my class, state of iteration, invocations from the crashing switch case.  
                                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBoxLowerCutoffChannel0.Text = Convert.ToString(pgmaPGMA2.GetLowerCutoff(u))));  thats what crashes, u (or i) is 16, it isnt supposed to ever be 16 . Its not altered anywhere but in the IF statement, as described

Comment: @JulianSchaefer Ask a new question, don't forget to post the full code, you'll get help for sure. Don't post image. Post it as text

Comment: @JulianSchaefer If you can edit the code into your current question, and it fills in the blanks, I will vote to re-open. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you may do that, I agree with @JMK Me too will vote for you to reopen.